# how to get the dayofyear values as 3 digit in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dayofyear

how to get the dayofyear values as 3 digit in snowflake?

Below query return as 68 but i should get '068' as 3 digits. Is anyone worked on this

`select DAYOFYEAR(current_timestamp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LPAD(DAYOFYEAR(current_timestamp), 3, '0') -- '068'
```